# Typescript how to define a type to check the if a string contain specific substring

Tags: typescript

With typescript, I want to define a type `T` which can check if the value is a substring with the given strings. It's like

```
const a = 'apple'
const b = 'banana'
const c = 'cat'
const d = 'dog'
type T1<typeof T, typeof U> = ?
const t1:T<a,b> = 'xyz apple banana' // pass
const t2:T<b,c> = 'banana cat abc' // pass
const t3:T<a,b> = 'abc xyz def' // error, as not contain 'apple' and 'banana'
```

How can I define that type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to check just one string value, that would be pretty simple.

```
type ContainsOneString<T extends string> = `${string}${T}${string}`

const tOneA: ContainsOneString<'cat'> = "i pet a cat" // pass
const tOneB: ContainsOneString<'cat'> = "i pet a dog" // error
```

This is a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) where the `${string}`'s act like wild cards, and `${T}` is the required substring that must be preset.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIM4HkEQMrABO6A5gDwAqUEAHsBAgCYZQZGkB8UAvFAAYASAN5tiCEgF9hFKSPbiJfAFBKAxojZRgOCAEEAXLEQp02XATHkA5KuTArXXgCJUUO9GRRbwJ1AD0flBgyBgYahrAWjoAQobwSGiYOhakZDZ2DjxQLm70blCMcCS+AdSEhHCEKkpAA)

---

Extending that to two strings is trickier, mainly because you don't know the order.

To get around that you can use a union type, where `T` before `U` is one member, and `U` before `T` is the other member:

```
type TwoStrings<T extends string, U extends string> =
  `${string}${T}${string}${U}${string}`

type ContainsTwoStrings<T extends string, U extends string> =
  TwoStrings<T, U> | TwoStrings<U, T>

const t1: ContainsTwoStrings<'apple', 'banana'> = 'xyz apple banana' // pass
const t2: ContainsTwoStrings<'banana', 'cat'> = 'banana cat abc' // pass
const t3: ContainsTwoStrings<'apple', 'banana'> = 'abc xyz def' // error, as not contain 'apple' and 'banana'
```

Here `TwoStrings` is a helper type that defines a string where one substring is first, and the other is second. Then `ContainsTwoStrings` is a union of the `T` then `U` case, and the `U` then `T` case.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=110&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg7gewMrAE4EsB2BzAzgHhiggA9gJMATXKXNLbAGigFViyLrb6cA+KALwAoKFAAGAEgDedDDgC+0mIpk9sKlitkN5YoUNCQoAYQSZgAQyy54yNQSKlyVGtpzM2Tzq7X9ho2xQ5PEIPfgAfWEQghgIWZhhefQBjMzooYABGAC4TM0trQPt8AHILMDAAGwgS5hKAIwtMJosSvygSkhAALyhyquhG5uaSqAB6MagwC1xcIVTMdOAAJlzTcytFouCCBpaRuuSLYDbBDqGWqCPgPvrk0YmpmbmFpYBmNfzNm2jisorqrVzvtWu0yncoF1epQIAAzB6TCCoVAIVDMGZQTAIG4LAqYDr9QF9KjA4atIA)